# Configuration files meta data usage in recipes

Tags: yocto

If a recipe want the meta data of a .inc file then it includes in .bb file. 
How meta data in .conf files are used in recipes(.bb files).

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? If I understand you correctly, any bitbake variable in configuration files `(.conf)` are available in every recipes.

Comment: The variables in a .conf file under one layer can be accessed inside the recipes located in another layer without referring them(i.e without including the .conf files).

Comment: Indeed, but doing so creates a dependancy to that other layer.

Comment: Maybe try to add an example in your original post, there could be cleaner ways for what you need.